# rbenv, bundler, binstubs… confusion

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv

I'm developing a gem which should install an executable.

At the moment I have a file at `bin/myexec` which does the work. I've got the line `gem.executables = 'myexec'` in my gemspec, and when I build and install the gem I can do `bundle exec myexec` anywhere and run my code - sweet.

I'm using rbenv, so I expect some slight shenanigans with binaries, but when I install this gem I need to always `bundle exec myexec` and I can't just `myexec`. I've poured over other gems (like `guard`) to see if there's some quirk of the .gemspec which implies that a rbenv binstub should be created, but I can't see anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your gem in another project and you installed it using bundler you have to stick with `bundle exec myexec`. To use your gem system wide you should install it using the `gem` command and `rbenv rehash` your environment.

I hope this helps, otherwise it would be nice if you provided some more information how you are using bundler etc.

Comment: I'd totally forgotten about `rbenv rehash` - perfect, thanks!